# Modifying an existing patented formula to create a totally new non obvious product

Tags: legal

I Modified an existing patented formula to create a totally new non obvious formula product and in a different field. Their product formula is in cosmetics and my modified formula is in let's say automotive. Is this also patentable?

Comment: I'd suggest your question is too broad to be able to answer.  It would depend on the nature of their patent and any declarations of "obvious" or "non-obvious" are a PITA to establish during the patenting process.  I've had to tell people, "Really, it's obvious?  Then why haven't the last 12 billion people seen it?" just to fall on deaf ears... they were convinced of their own correctness.

Comment: Thx Jeremy,....I basically added ingredients to an existing formula that I purchased to create a totally new formula in a different category.

Comment: BTW its a A chemical formula.